# Compare only date part from DateTime being aware of Timezone offset in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core

Let say I need to filter records for date `2020-03-13` from following UTC Dates.

```
2020-03-13T11:40:37.552Z,
2020-03-13T13:40:37.552Z,
2020-03-13T19:40:37.552Z,
2020-03-13T21:40:37.552Z
```

From client's prospective (having timezone offset of `UTC+5`) last two records occured on `2020-03-14` and only first two records should be returned. How can I achieve this?
Currently I am doing it like
`dbDate.Date == clientDate.Date` to filter records but it's returning all the records.

Comment: Seems like you need to use `DateTime.ToLocalTime.Date`

Comment: But in that case the local time would be of the server on which the application is hosted, not the client using it.

Answer (score 2):

Two options to consider:

- Convert all the dates into your client's time zone, then compare the `Date` property of each result with 2020-03-13
- Convert the start of 2020-03-13 and the start of 2020-03-14 *from* your client's time zone into UTC, and then filter based on that range (with an inclusive start and an exclusive end)

The latter is potentially more efficient, using only two conversions - but it uses the harder-to-reason about "local to UTC" conversion (where you need to worry about "what happens if midnight on the date in question doesn't exist or occurs twice due to DST conversions)... whereas the "convert UTC to local time" conversion is always unambiguous.

I'd probably go for the first option unless efficiency is a significant concern.

In terms of efficiency, note that if the database stores UTC, you can perform the conversions for the second option locally, then get the database to do all the filtering there. I don't know how simple it is to get the database to filter including a conversion from UTC to the target time zone. If that's tricky, you could at least do *some* filtering in the database by assuming the user's UTC offset will never be more than +/- 14 hours - so you can get all records with a UTC value in that "maximal possible window" and then finish the filtering locally by converting each value in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know client's timezone, convert client's datetime to UTC first

Answer (score 0):

This is basically Jon Skeet's suggestion in code.

First get the dates into a DateTime object in UTC. Then convert to the clients time zone and check if the date matches your criteria.

```
var datesAsStrings = new string[]
{
  "2020-03-13T11:40:37.552Z",
  "2020-03-13T13:40:37.552Z",
  "2020-03-13T19:40:37.552Z",
  "2020-03-13T21:40:37.552Z"
};

foreach (var date in datesAsStrings)
{
  var utcDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
  var clientLocalTimeZoneDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDate, TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("x", TimeSpan.FromHours(+5), "x", "x"));
  if (clientLocalTimeZoneDate.Date == new DateTime(2020, 3, 14))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(date);
  }
}
```

Instead of creating a custom time zone, you should find the one you need by calling `TimeZoneInfo.FindTimeZoneById` with the time zone id of your client.